# VNC Viewer on Firefox web

Tags: firefox, vnc

I want to be able to connect VNC Viewer with Firefox using the IP number and the password from the computer that I want to see the desktop!

The problems is: I just can't. What do I have to install, besides Java to be able to connect using Firefox? I alredy have de VNCViewer installed with Wine but I wanted to use de FileTransfer opition that is only available when you acess it using the web VNC.

Comment: Any reason to not use a native Ubuntu VNC viewer?

Answer (score 3):

**Running from a web browser**

The VNC servers also contain a small web server. If you connect to this with a web browser, you can download the Java version of the viewer, and use this to view the server. You can then see your desktop from any Java-capable browser, unless you are using a proxy to connect to the web. The server listens for HTTP connections on port 5800+display number. So to view display 2 on machine `ADDRESS`, you would point your web browser at:

`http://ADDRESS:5802/`

The applet will prompt you for your password, and should then display the desktop.

**Running as an application**

You can run the viewer outside a browser using, for example:

`java -jar vncviewer ADDRESS:2`

The precise command line will depend on your particular Java installation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have tried to type de http:// at my wed browser but it is unable to connect. The reason is because the server of the IP machine i trying to see is taking to long to reply. But when I open the VNC Viewer using the wine application it works fine... I already have Java7 installed! thanks

Comment: what is your vnc server?

Answer (score 0):

You can connect from Linux-Firefox VNC with this web site - http://www.onlinevnc.com/ It uses Flash VNC viewer and Java does not required. Other good news it support File Transfer based on pure FTP.

P.S. Look how can be configured FTP engine - http://www.onlinevnc.com/support/configuring-ftp-based-file-transfer.html

Comment: Dead link now...